# Confused about the way this .htaccess rule is supposed to work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

in my php I have

```
header("Location: /users/" . $_SESSION['user']);
```

it loads this into the browser

```
foo.bar/users/s2xi
```

which gives me a 404 Not Found error, I can understand up to the part where the directory users doesn't exist, but isn't my RewriteRule supposed to take care of that?

Edit: My complete .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.foo.bar/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+)(/)?$ users.php?type=$1&user=$2 [NC,R]
#RewriteRule ^users/?$ users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^(admin)/(.+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)$ users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

#error codes
RewriteRule ^/error/([^/]+)/ error.php?code=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? And is RewriteEngine on?

Comment: its in the root, and ya i have everything configured nicely. Its just this little snippet thats not playing nice with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)$ users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also make sure users.php is in a right directory. If it's in root directory, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)$ /users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: ya my users.php is in the root directory. No matter what I try I can't get the browser to pick it up as a virtual directory. I updated my post with my whole htaccess file

Comment: never mind, my stupid coda wasn't uploading my changes to my htaccess and so what ever i did was never really appended to the file and uploaded ;(